# Does the UIScrollView automatically adjust contentOffset to fit inside the safe area?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView and 3 UIViews that I add to it.

I have triple checked the frame of the UIScrollView, the frame of the UIViews, it's contentOffset, the frame of the superview, generally everything relevant.

For some reason, this is what appears when I set the contentOffset to be (0,0):

[image]

There's no view in my project that starts from that offset origin point.

The scrollView assumes (0, 0) to be something around (0, 50) which is the height of the navigation bar even though I'm not using one.

**EDIT**

Weird enough if I open the app while the device is in landscape mode the contentOffset behaves normal. So, it has to be some automatic adjustment because of the chin of the device.

**EDIT 2**

I opened the app on a device without a chin (iPhone 8) then the contentOffset automatically adjusts to the height of the status bar. Meaning (0, 0) is not (0, 0) but (0, heightOfStatusBar).

**EDIT 3**

On an iPad it behaves normally even though iPads do have a status bar!

***How do I fix this to be (0,0) in every case ?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIScrollView` has a property where it "insets" the content so that the safe areas are not overlapped.

It can be changed by setting setting the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` property of the `UIScrollView` instance like so:

```swift
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Note that it is not the `contentOffset`, but `contentInset` that gets adjusted. This is why the content offset is still `(0, 0)` in all cases.

Also, if you are building for an iOS Development Target lower than iOS 11.0, you might get a build error. In that case you can use the following code instead.

```swift
if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

#### References

[Apple Developer Docs - contentinsetadjustmentbehavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior)

Answer (score 0):

No, contentOffset does not affect to safe area and vice versa.
contentOffset is used for programming scroll inside scrollView.

If you want to link UIScrollView to frame's bounds you have to use Autolayout and activate some constraints. Step by step:

1. set property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints of scroll view to false
   scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
2. init constraints
3. activate constrains (in viewDidLoad)

scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

```
    let constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        scrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

As a result your scroll view will be linked to edges of phone bounds. And contentOffset wil be equal (0, 0). Instead if you want to link scrollView to safe area you have to do use view.layoutMarginsGuide, where you can find various anchors.

Every UIView object works with parent view coordinating system. Your scrollView does not know anything about status bar, navigation bar and toolbars. For example, frame origin of any UIView is (0,0).

So, in summary:

1. to link you scroll view to safe area you need to set constraints.
2. contentOffset is used for programming scroll inside scrollView.